# Compute $\int_0^x \sqrt{s(2-s)}\, ds $

Tags: calculus, integration

Could anyone shed some light on how to compute the following two integrals?
$$ \int_0^x \sqrt{s(2-s)}\, ds \ \ \textrm{ for $0<x<1$}, $$
and 
$$\int_x^0 \sqrt{s(s-2)}\, ds \ \ \textrm{ for $-1<x<0$}. $$

Comment: hint: trigonometric substitution $s=2sin^2(\theta)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution without Finding Antiderivative**: Observe
\begin{align}
\int^x_0\sqrt{2s-s^2}\ ds = \int^x_0\sqrt{1-(1-s)^2}\ ds = \int^{1}_{1-x} \sqrt{1-s^2}\ ds
\end{align}
which is just the area underneath the unit semi-circle from $1-x$ to $1$. But that area is given by sector of the disk minus a right triangle, i.e. we have
\begin{align}
\int^1_{1-x} \sqrt{1-s^2}\ ds =&\ \text{ area of sector} - \text{ area of triangle}\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\theta -\frac{1}{2}(1-x)\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2} \\
=&\  \frac{1}{2}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}{1-x} - \frac{1}{2}(1-x)\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
where $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$ is the angle of the sector.

**Additional Remark**: Notice the area underneath the unit semi-circle from $1-x$ to $1$ is also equal to the area of quarter disk in the first quadrant minus the area underneath the unit semi-circle from $0$ to $1-x$, let us call that $A$. Observe $A$ is actually the sum of a sector and a right triangle, i.e. 
\begin{align}
A =&\ \text{ right triangle } + \text{ sector of disk}\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2} (1-x)\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right).
\end{align} 
Using the trig identity
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \right) = \cos\theta
\end{align}
and the fact that
\begin{align}
\tan\theta = \frac{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}{1-x}
\end{align}
then we arrive at the conclusion that
\begin{align}
\cos\theta = 1-x.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta = \arcsin\cos\theta = \arcsin(1-x)
\end{align}
which also means
\begin{align}
A = \frac{1}{2}(1-x)\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(1-x)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int^1_{1-x}\sqrt{1-s^2}\ ds =&\ \frac{\pi}{4}- A\\
=&\ \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2} - \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(1-x).
\end{align}

Comment: This is neat! The expression in the book involves $\arcsin$ thou, specifically it says that the first integral equals $\frac{1}{2}(1-x)\sqrt{x(2-x)} - \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(x-1) + \frac{\pi}{4}$. I will check this later but I am willing to believe that this would equal your given expression (:

Answer (score 2):

$$s(2-s)=1^2-(s-1)^2$$

Now use $\#8$ of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ13/integ13.html)

See also: [Trouble solving $\int\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617421/trouble-solving-int-sqrt1-x2-dx/617447)

$$s(s-2)=(s-1)^2-1^2$$

Now use $\#8$ of [this](http://amser.org/index.php?P=AMSER--ResourceFrame&resourceId=2416)