# u-substitution for a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{4- x^2} dx$$

I am thinking of doing a u-substitution of the whole term inside the root. If I do this, I need to change the limits of the integral. Doing so, the new limits would be equal (0=0). Doesn't this mean that the value of the integral would be 0?

Comment: hint: $\sqrt{4-x^2}=\sqrt{4-(-x)^2}$

Comment: Similar problem-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617421/trouble-solving-int-sqrt1-x2-dx?rq=1

Comment: If $f(x)$ is even, $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=2 \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

Comment: Before downvoting, consider if in fact the OP is asking why the substitution $u = 4 - x^2$ doesn’t work (and not necessarily just asking for help evaluating the integral). I don’t think it’s uncommon for a first calc class to gloss over these kinds of things...

Comment: Yes, that was the point of my question. Wanted to know what happens when a substitution returns this issue. @josé-carlos-santos and cy-aries provided the much needed clarification. Thank you both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble solving $\int\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617421/trouble-solving-int-sqrt1-x2-dx)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380669/proof-all-integrals-are-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why $0$? If you do the natural substitution ($x=2\sin u$ and $\mathrm dx=2\cos u\,\mathrm du$), then the limits will be $\pm\frac\pi2$.

Comment: If I do the substitution $4-x^2=u$, I get for both limits $0$.

Where does $x=sinu$ come from?

Comment: @jimogios With the substitution that I mentioned, your integral becomes$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\cos^2u\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: Ok, but how do we end up with this?

Comment: @jimogios I'm sorry. I made a mistake: it should have been $x=2\sin y$ (I've edited my answer). Now, one usus the fact that$$\cos^2u=\frac{1+\cos(2u)}{2}.$$

Comment: I don't understand. What is the process with which I end up with the integral that you show in the previous comment?

Comment: $$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\sqrt{4-(2\sin u)^2}2\cos u\,\mathrm du=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}4\cos^2u\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: Ok now I got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way is to think this as surface of a semi circle with radius $2$. Then the answer is $2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

The integral can be found with the substitution $x=\sin \theta$.

If we let $u=4-x^2$. Then $du=-2xdx$.

Note that $x=\sqrt{4-u}$ if $x\ge 0$ and $x=-\sqrt{4-u}$ if $x<0$.

So, $\displaystyle dx=\frac{du}{-2\sqrt{4-u}}$ if $x\ge 0$ and $\displaystyle dx=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{4-u}}$ if $x\le 0$.

So we actually do not have $\displaystyle \int_0^0 \frac{\sqrt{u}du}{-2\sqrt{4-u}}$.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-2}^2\sqrt{4-x^2}dx&=\int_{-2}^0\sqrt{4-x^2}dx+\int_0^2\sqrt{4-x^2}dx\\
&=\int_0^4 \frac{\sqrt{u}du}{2\sqrt{4-u}}+\int_4^0 \frac{\sqrt{u}du}{-2\sqrt{4-u}}\\
&=\int_0^4 \frac{\sqrt{u}du}{2\sqrt{4-u}}+\int_0^4 \frac{\sqrt{u}du}{2\sqrt{4-u}}\\
&=\int_0^4 \frac{\sqrt{u}du}{\sqrt{4-u}}
\end{align*}

This does not help us to find the integral. But at least the integral is not $0$.

Comment: You are right. But what is the exact process of deriving those two integrals with limits of 0 and 4?

Comment: This substitution makes the integral complicated. The standard substitution is $x=\sin\theta$, as mentioned by José Carlos Santos.

Comment: @jimogios I will edit my answer to give more details.